# MQ JMS reconnect - exception listener

Tags: ibm-mq

MQ version 7.5.0.4

Is there a way of getting a notification when the connection is lost. What I can se I only get an error when the timeout has been reached. (`JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.`)

```
       mqcf.setConnectionNameList(host); // "host1(1414),host2(1414)";
        mqcf.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
        mqcf.setClientReconnectTimeout(100); // seconds

        ExceptionListener exceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onException(JMSException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getErrorCode() + " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };


        // need to reconnect on exception..! 
        connection.setExceptionListener(exceptionListener);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Exception Listener for events (even reconnection) is outside of the scope of the JMS Specification. The strict definition is that that should be fired only for when a connection is broken - and the correct course of action is to recreate the connection.  (note that various vendors MQ included do provide extensions - so it's always worth raising the requirement!)

In the JavaSE environment you have here, it's possible to set the autoreconnect. In managed environments that's not supported so you do actually have to listen for the connection broken and then the applicaiton needs to redrive createConnection().  The connectionNameList is then 'walked' to find a QM that is running.

Comment: Agreed on the JMS part. I am using Akka/Scala :) There is a camel connector but ... 

For managed connections see: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/ccdts_connection_namelists_load_balancers_and_code_stubs?lang=en
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1303_broadhurst/1303_broadhurst-pdf.pdf

Comment: Good links those - the formal support for reconnect is at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508357

Answer (score 1):

Use the linked exception to get more details. In my tested I ended the queue manager without the reconnect option, hence the MQRC 2161 reason code.

code:

```
            @Override
            public void onException(JMSException e) {
                System.out.println(e);//e.getErrorCode() + " " + e.getMessage());
                if(e.getLinkedException() != null)
                    System.out.println(e.getLinkedException());
            }
```

Exception details.

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
An error has occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS connection.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2161' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_QUIESCING').
```

Comment: Shashi, yes but that only happens after the setClientReconnectTimeout has expiered. I dont think one could enlist a *API* listner to get to know that the client is trying to reconnnect.